# Width of position:absolute input tag not correct on iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad

I'm trying to position an input element inside a div, with a background, which I need to size and position absolute. It works ok on PC but I cannot get it right on iPad without using completely different values.

Appearence on PC

[image: Appearence on PC]

Appearence on iPad

[image]

Html:

```
<div id="container">
    <input class="input-pc" type="text"/>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="container">
    <input class="input-ipad" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#container{
    background-color: #343434;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 26px;
}

.input-pc {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    width: 196px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #E8FB46;
    border: none;
}

.input-ipad {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius:0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    width: 186px;
    height: 17px;
    background-color: #E8FB46;
    border: none;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RichardHoultz/pgn7N/6/) with the two styles which work on PC and iPad.

Is there a way to get the two input fields to be correctly contained on the two platforms?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I guess this should work on both the devices as I am not using any relative/absolute positioning. Instead, I am only making use of simple CSS. This is the html:

```
<div id="newContainer">
    <input class="input" type="text"/>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

div {
    margin:20px 0 0 20px;
}
#newContainer{
    background-color: #343434;
    width: 200px;
    height: 23px;
    padding:1px 2px 0px 2px;
    border:0;
}

.input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #E8FB46;
    border: none;
}
```

You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/6mVHJ/2/

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't do the trick. On iPad the yellow input box stretches over the right side of the div... I've updated my fiddle to use padding instead as I tried this.  
[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RichardHoultz/pgn7N/8/)